# Place image between nodes in tikz: How to achieve precise positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I am trying to include a background image in a tikz/pgf drawing. I need to be able to draw nodes directly on certain features of the image, it thus needs to be precisely adjusted.

This would be easiest if I could somehow fix it to two nodes defining the corners of the image, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {a};
\includegraphics{something.png}
\node at (2,2) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course this does not do what I want, i.e. scaling the image so that it its top-right corner is at (2,2) and the bottom-left corner at (0,0):

[image]

Comment: please have a look at this canonical question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @percusse led me to the right answer. It involves using the scope environment.

The following code is taken from @Caramdir's answer in [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (img) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
\coordinate (a) at (img.south west);
\coordinate (b) at (img.north east);
\draw[blue,thick] (a)--(b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's  a good start, but doesn't allow me "to draw nodes directly on certain features of the image". I want to be able to draw a node at (1.5,1) and be certain it appears in the image at that coordinate

Comment: If you tell me, what `(1.5,1)` refers to, I'll be happy to adjust the code. Does that mean at (1.5 x width of the image, 1 x height of the image)? See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415989/121799).

Comment: My background image is a satellite image of which I know the corners' longitudes and latitude. I want to draw nodes on certain POIs based on their long/lat.

Comment: But since you posted already an answer yourself, I guess my answer is obsolete, right?

Comment: The one I posted is a working work-around, but not very elegant and quite hacky in my final implementation. If you have a solution that works better I'd be very grateful

Comment: @sheß Well, your question is already marked a duplicate :-( What you might want to add is a transformation that allows you to use the longitude and latitude coordinates directly. This can be done by modifying [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415994/121799) (or also [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/415989/edit)) answer.